# How to create a pure custom color for Gmail tags

Tags: gmail

Right now I can only pick from a very limited gradient for background/text color for tabs in Gmail like so:

[image]

I would like to truly customize them (i.e. provide hex values or chose from a picker). How can I do that?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't without some local CSS hackery.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, pick a selected checkbox and inspect it. You should see three RGB values (One in the "title" of the box, one in its style, and one in the "aria-label" of the overall element). I edited all three and got it to work, but my guess would be that editing just the "aria-label" and/or the "title" should work.